# Как зациклить данный скрипт?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здраствуйте, как можно зациклить данный скрипт? При попытке использовать цикл с таймером на 10 минут выходит ошибка

Вот скрипт:

```
import amino
import time

client = amino.Client()
client.login(email='`введите сюда код`', password='`введите сюда код`')
subclient = amino.SubClient(comId= `введите сюда код`, profile=client.profile)

while 1 == 1:
    subclient.flag(reason = 'текст', flagType = 200, userId = '`введите сюда код`')
    time.sleep(600)
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents\pythonProject\main1.py", line 12, in <module>
    time.sleep(600)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: Не добавляйте скриншоты кода. Добавляйте сам код в вопрос

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Ошибка означает, что кто-то нажал Ctrl+C

Comment: Да нет, взять код было негде особо, по этому сам додумывал моменты. Всё работает как необходимо, но когда я добавил цикл, он не сработал и выдал ошибку

Comment: KeyboardInterrupt буквально означает, что вы сами прекратили работу программы, например нажали Ctrl+C или кнопку останова в PyCharm.

Comment: Да, так и есть. Позже разобрался, это сообщение выходило когда я прекращал скрипт, но к сожалению данный скрипт не выполняет свою роль циклично. От знакомых слышал, что нужен хост сервер, чтобы данный api заработал и выполнял действие множество раз.